# Why does tilting a diffraction grating produce a parabolic pattern?

Tags: visible-light, interference, diffraction

I was using diffraction gratings, when I noticed that tilting them gives a parabolic pattern. If I tilt the top towards the screen, it gives a parabola with concave upward; while tilting the top away from the screen gives a parabola with concave downward.

Changing the number of lines on the grating does not affect the shape of the parabola. However, increasing the tilt increases the curvature.

How can this be explained? Further, is it even a parabola or some other conic section?

EDIT: Here, screen just means the surface on which the pattern is formed.
I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWrmnkFsIKw&t=42s) showing the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

From your description, it sounds like you were creating a [Moiré pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) between the fine spacing of the lines in the diffraction grating and the fine spacing of the pixels on your screen arranged in a cartesian pattern.  Tilting the grating toward or away from the screen changes the apparent closeness of the lines in the grating at the top vs. at the bottom from your perspective (the part of the grating closer to you looks bigger and hence more coarsely spaced lines, while the part tilted away from you is farther away and hence looks smaller with finer spaced lines).  This could produce the parabola-like curve you described.

A way to test this hypothesis would be to move the grating closer to or farther away from the screen, and see if that changes the size of the parabola.  Alternatively, try rotating the grating by 45 degrees so that the grating lines no longer line up with the pixel cartesian grid of the screen.  This should give rise to a new pattern.

Fun aside: this is also the same reason why taking a picture of a screen with a digital camera (such as your phone) produces weird lines.  Moiré patterns form between pixels of the screen and pixels of the camera.

Comment: I don't mean a digital screen, by the word screen; rather just a surface on which the pattern is formed. I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWrmnkFsIKw&t=42s) that demonstrates the same effect as I am describing. If this is a Moiré pattern somehow (I don't have a good knowledge of those), what are the two grids or similar patterns that light is passing through (like the fine spacing between diffraction grating and pixels you mentioned)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is conical diffraction? Here is a paper describing it (unfortunately, behind a paywall): https://www.osapublishing.org/ao/abstract.cfm?uri=ao-37-34-8158

They have some neat graphical aids / geometric arguments to describe the phenomenon (which is surprisingly subtle!!!)

Answer (score 0):

https://images.app.goo.gl/LbkduAbBLXjHKh598

The distance (D) between the grating and the screen is very important as shown in the attached formula. In your description, tilting the diffraction grating causes the top or the bottom to be closer to the screen than the other. This makes the equation different for the top and the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The effect, which is indeed sometimes called "conical diffraction", is very well known and well understood - although it might be a bit opaque for a person who's not familiar with 3D trigonometry.  [Here is a good place to go](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335454256_Understanding_diffraction_grating_behavior_including_conical_diffraction_and_Rayleigh_anomalies_from_transmission_gratings) for a paper that describes it.  First look at Figure 6.